# What is the purpose of a battery on a GPS receiver?

Tags: batteries, gps

My GPS receiver has a small *MS621FE* battery:

[image: GPS receiver PCB]

Any ideas what might be the purpose of a battery on a GPS receiver?

Comment: Fast restart due to retention of ephemeris & almanac.  Might be an RTC on there as well.

Comment: Might also have been cheaper/easier to use the battery to store persistent data (user settings, etc) in ram rather than adding an additional rom chip.

Comment: This has been discussed in [this thread](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/53184/7036) (although from a different angle).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[According to the datasheet:](http://www.chinesegps.com/downloads/ET-662%20user%20manual%20V2.2.pdf)

> **VBAT**
>
> This is the battery backup power for the SRAM and RTC when main power is off. Without the external backup battery, ET-662 will always execute a cold star[t] after turning on. To achieve the faster start-up offered by a hot or warm start, a backup battery must be connected. The battery voltage should be between 2.0V and 3.5V

As mentioned in the comments, the main reason this saves time is that it avoids having to wait for the "almanac" of GPS satellite positions to be downloaded.

Comment: +1 for RTFM - a skill that many people are sadly lacking.